# Web scraping with click

Tags: excel, vba

The click does not work, i tried in every way.

Do you have any suggestions? Thanks

> 

```
<button class="item-cover item-cover-md item-cover-default
item-cover-default-md" id="select-3-0" aria-disabled="false"
aria-haspopup="true" aria-labelledby="lbl-3" type="button"
ion-button="item-cover"><span class="button-inner"></span><div
class="button-effect" style="transition:transform 541ms, opacity 379ms
162ms; width: 240px; height: 240px; opacity: 0; transform:
translate3d(988px, -90px, 0px) scale(1);"></div></button>
```

I tray

```
Doc.querySelector("[id ='select-3-0']").Click

Doc.getElementById("select-3-0").Click
```

Comment: please, write a more explicit question, and provide more information about your problem

Comment: Yeah, sorry if I haven't been clear.
I have to click on a radio button and what i post above is the HTML code, but it doesn't take the click event.
What am i doing wrong?

I tried with
--->
Set Doc = IE.Document
Doc.querySelector("[id ='select-3-0']").Click
or
Doc.getElementById("select-3-0").Click

but nothing happens.

Comment: Have you checked whether there are any associated [event listeners](https://www.stanleyulili.com/javascript/how-to-find-event-listeners-on-a-dom-node-when-debugging/)? You may need to create an htmlevent attach it to the relevant button and dispatch it.

Comment: Thanks for the reply but I don't think it's an event problem because it doesn't select the radio button